# Showing multiple attributes for Rails drop down menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, html-select

I'm working my edit view and trying to implement a drop down box which shows multiple attributes from a model. I have an equipment model which includes an item description and an item serial number. Is there a way to implement this so that the drop down menu shows Item Description - Serial Number?

I was thinking about using a method to combine the 2 attributes into a single virtual attribute and display it, but I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this first.

Comment: I think the best way is it, to make a View-Helper.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you want select options to be displayed like "[DESCRIPTION] - [SERIAL NUMBER]" in the list of options?

Comment: @Niko Efimov - Yea thats it exactly, theyre both separate attributes in the model, Im trying to display them both so the user can see the serial number for the equipment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select_tag :equipment, options_for_select(Equipment.all.collect {|e| ["#{e.description} - #{e.serial}", e.id] }), :include_blank => true
```

Comment: I swapped the e.id and the string so the string was displayed in the drop down box and the id was listed as the option value

Comment: How would you add in :include_blank=> true? I've been playing around with it and cant seem to get it to work.